# MySql query - If table two tables have same data, select from more important table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables

rules, default_client_rules and client_rules

Rules contains a list of all the rules, their names, parameters etc.

default_client_rules has a list of rules that applies to all users. Table:

```
`id`, `rule_id`, `num_required`
```

The user can also create their own rules stored in client_rules.

```
`id`, `rule_id, `num_required`
```

The user can create their own rules that would override the default rules so in my tables I might have:

default_client_rules
    `21`, `3`, `0`

client_rules
    `7`, `3`, `1`

The client rules takes precedence over the default client rules table. I want to write a query to display all rules. The bit I'm having trouble with is, in the scenario above when there is an entry in client_rules for the same rule as in default_client_rules I only want to select the client_rules entry.

Comment: Put your code and start from there

Comment: `COALESCE` maybe? Something like `COALESCE(client_rule, default_client_rule)`.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: you cannot conditionally return additional fields based on criteria, the number of fields returned is something you must code into the query. at best, you could return a value when there is not a match, and `NULL` when there is a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work. It basically does a left join of the client rules, assuming that there will always be a default rule. It does a check to see if client_rule.rule_id is null. If it is null, it uses the default value, otherwise it uses the client rule value.

```
select 
  dcr.rule_id,
  if(isnull(cr.rule_id), dcr.num_required, cr.num_required) as num_required,
  if(isnull(cr.rule_id), dcr.id, cr.id) as id
FROM default_client_rules dcr LEFT JOIN client_rules cr 
ON dcr.rule_id=cr.rule_id
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7138b9).